# move_uploaded_file() showing successful but not working

Tags: php, html, image, file-upload, upload

I am using php to upload and move a file to a desired location...
while using move_uploaded_file, it says that the file has moved successfully but the file does not show up in the directory.
THE HTML AND PHP CODE IS BELOW...

```
 <form action="test_upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
<label for="test_pic">Testing Picture</label>
<input type="file" name="test_pic" size="30" /><br />
</fieldset>

<fieldset>

<input type="submit" value="submit" />

</fieldset>
</form>
```

THe php goes like :

```
    <?php


$image_fieldname = "test_pic";
$upload_dir = "/vidit";
$display_message ='none';

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$image_fieldname]['tmp_name'],$upload_dir) && is_writable($upload_dir)){
    $display_message = "file moved successfully";
    }
    else{
        $display_message = " STILL DID NOT MOVE";
            }



?>
```

when i run this page and upload a legitimate file - the test_upload.php echoes file uploaded successfully. but when i head on to the folder "vidit" in the root of the web page. the folder is empty...

I am using wamp server .

Comment: the folder vidit in your wamp server could have an only readable premission so check the premission of the vidit folder to make sure its writable

Comment: also change the order in the `if` condition, so that it becomes 'if (is_writable($upload_dir) && move_uploaded_file(...) {`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to **append filename into your destination path**. Try as below

```
$doc_path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$image_fieldname]['tmp_name'],$doc_path.$upload_dir.'/'.$_FILES[$image_fieldname]['name']) && is_writable($upload_dir)){
    $display_message = "file moved successfully";
}
else{
    $display_message = " STILL DID NOT MOVE";
}
```

See PHP Manual for reference. http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: now it says - failed to open stream  : No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\testing_upload\test_upload.php on line 9

Comment: @valiantb see edited answer & try. and also paste document_root path means absolute path to vidit.

Answer (score 0):

Use this it may work

```
$upload_dir = "vidit/";



      $uploadfile=($upload_dir.basename($_FILES['test_pic']['name']));

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['test_pic']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile) ) {


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $image_fieldname = "test_pic";
  $upload_dir = "/vidit";
  $display_message ='none';
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$image_fieldname]['tmp_name'],$upload_dir . '/' . $_FILES[$image_fieldname]['name'] && is_writable($upload_dir)) {
    $display_message = "file moved successfully";
  } else {
    $display_message = " STILL DID NOT MOVE";
  }
?>
```

Added indenting as well. The file name needs to be applied, or it's like uploading the file as a extensionless file.

Answer (score 0):

Create tmp directory in root(www) and change directory path definitely it works 
/ after your directory name is compulsory

$upload_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tmp/';